Appsync not working well at all with other dependencies
I have tried all solutions available on internet but don't see apollo client working with appsync subscriptions with React v18. It works with queries and mutations only.
I am using these packages
[
    "@apollo/client": "^3.10.3",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@iconify/react": "^4.1.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.1",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^6.3.7",
    "aws-appsync-auth-link": "^3.0.7",
    "aws-appsync-subscription-link": "^3.1.2",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "formik": "^2.4.5",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
    "i18next": "^23.7.11",
    "npm": "^10.2.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-cookie": "^6.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-helmet-async": "^2.0.4",
    "react-i18next": "^14.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.21.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "simplebar-react": "^3.2.4",
    "yup": "^1.3.3"
]

Here's my client
const url = API_URL;
const region = "eu-west-2";

const auth = {
  type: AUTH_TYPE.AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS,
  jwtToken: async () => {
    const { authToken } = await UserAuthService.getAuthTokens();
    return `${authToken}`;
  },
};

const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: API_URL });

const link = ApolloLink.from([
  createAuthLink({ url, region, auth }),
  createSubscriptionHandshakeLink(
    { url, region, auth, keepAliveTimeoutMs: 90000 },
    httpLink
  ),
]);

const wsLink = new WebSocketLink(new SubscriptionClient(APPSYNC_WSS_URL));

const splitLink = split(
  ({ query }) => {
    const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
    const test =
      definition.kind === "OperationDefinition" &&
      definition.operation === "subscription";

    console.log(`TESET RUESLT FOR QUERY `, test, query);
    return test;
  },
  wsLink,
  createAuthLink({ url, region, auth }).concat(httpLink)
);

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

// export const client = new ApolloClient({
//   link: splitLink,
//   cache: new InMemoryCache(),
// });

This is the error:
screenshot
Has anyone ever succeeded with work with Apollo client and appsync subscriptions with React version 18?
I tried react-apollo but does not my react version.
I expected appsync subscriptions work.
